# HDMI streaming on Raspberry Pi 4B with TC358743

Tags: hdmi, streaming

I'm looking to stream an HDMI signal wirelessly between two Pis, using a TC358743 on the camera port of the input Pi and playing video from the HDMI port of the output Pi. I'm quite new to Raspberry Pi so bear with me.

Here are some of my design parameters:

- Currently the video source will just be a laptop. The input stream will be 720p.
- Audio streaming is not required.
- While 60fps is preferable, 30fps is acceptable.
- A little bit of latency (<1s) is acceptable.
- I will have a dedicated WiFi network to support the video streaming.

I've tried [this tutorial](https://dantheiotman.com/2017/08/23/using-raspivid-for-low-latency-pi-zero-w-video-streaming/) which uses raspivid streaming over netcat to mplayer on the receiver. It seems to work very well with the actual Camera V2 module, but there is almost 10 seconds of latency with an HDMI input. This seems to be due to the processor taking a long time to decode the HDMI-CSI2 signals. However, the HDMI signal plays natively with excellent resolution and almost no latency.

I'm not sure where to go from here. Currently I'm attempting to replace raspivid with V4L2, but I can't figure out how to pipe that into netcat and I'm not sure if it will have the same latency issues when streaming.

Where should I go from here? Any other methods I can try?

(I understand there are commercial wireless HDMI products out there but I'd like to eventually expand this project to include some custom features on the Pis.)